# How does it work push empty array into an empty array

Tags: javascript

```
var ar = []; 
console.log(ar.push([]));   // 1
```

I expected the log to be `[[]]`, but it show me 1. What is going on above the code.

Comment: That is not how push works. Please [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: `push()` returns *The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.*

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), the `Array#push` returns:

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was called.

So, in your case, as you are pushing an element to an empty array - which makes the length 1 - hence the result.

In case you wish to confirm:

```js
// Empty array.
var arr = [];

// Push an item: result = 1
console.log(arr.push([]));

// Push another item: result = 2
console.log(arr.push([]));
```